# Chrome theme: How to change the colour of the URL text when hovered over a link on a web page?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I am very new to developing Chrome themes. Everything went well but when I hover mouse pointer over a link, the URL displayed at the bottom left side is not readable because of its font color! How can I change the font color?

[image: URL font]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The color of the status bar is derived from the color of the `toolbar` and the color of its text is from the `tab_text`.  Well it was in Chrome 6 but Im pretty sure the things where one color comes from another color and still all the same.  Have a look at an old doc that lists those things....
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1jt9vdUY9O5IMm6Zoi2Kz0LWFfFZpvP69qjy6PoGsEoA
...like I said I havent updated it in ages (Chrome 6), but those things should still be the same.

Comment: @PAEz, Wow that docs is ooolllld, Where is the new documentation for themes now?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an updated answer:

I discovered that some themes that are generated with Chrome Apps like, My Chrome Theme, create JSON for "toolbar". By default it gives it a transparency, like so: `"toolbar":[228,228,228, 0.6],`

You'll need to remove the last number, which is the alpha. So it just looks like this: `"toolbar":[228,228,228],`

Now it works perfectly. Enjoy!

Answer (score -3):

Add color to `<a>` tag in CSS or inline style.

> a {
>                   color: #FF0000;
>                   text-decoration: none;
>               }

```
    a:hover 
    {
             color:#00FF00; 
             text-decoration:none; 
             cursor:pointer;  
     }
```

Comment: This is not a CSS question, it's JSON for Chrome Themes.