# Can I Edit a Google Chrome Theme?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, themes, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-theme

I downloaded some themes from the Chrome Web Store. Is there any way I can edit these themes?

(I want to change colors, buttons etc.)

If yes, how?
If no, why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A theme is a special kind of extension that changes the way the browser looks. Themes are packaged like regular extensions, but they don't contain JavaScript or HTML code. **You can download any theme and modify it by editing the manifest.json file.**

Colors are in RGB format. To find the strings you can use within the "colors" field, look for kColor* strings in theme_service.cc. Image resources use paths relative to the root of the extension. You can override any of the images that are specified by kThemeableImages in theme_service.cc. Just remove the "IDR_" and convert the remaining characters to lowercase.

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes

Comment: You can use [CRX viewer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to download a ZIP of the theme from Web Store. Don't forget to remove `_metadata` folder.

Comment: @aygul, The documentation there is **weak**. Even the page linked by https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906057/632951 does better.

Comment: @alex351 check out this github, it works with the most recent chrome - https://github.com/mike-u/EditChromeThemes. Though you want to reference the links on https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes for the most up to date tints, colors, etc you can use.

Comment: doesn't work in chromium. changes are ignored. I even wiped the entire contents of the theme section in the respective manifest.json and deleted the cachedTheme.pak file too.

Comment: I was also having trouble using the modified manifest.json in Chrome 92.
Here's what eventually worked: [1] copied the manifest.json to a new directory (probably not needed, but good for my sanity), [2] Navigate to chrome://extensions/ [3] Enable "Developer mode".
[4] Click "Load unpacked" and choose the directory containing the manifest.json.
[5] Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

You can find it in your appdata folders. Mine was located at:

```
C:\Users\home\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User    
Data\Default\Extensions\mcphcjcjgkjmbphkfjleamgkinaeebnm\1.1_0
```

You might just want to make a search query in your appdata for "manifest.json", and open a few until you find it.

Comment: Ah, mcphcjcjgkjmbphkfjleamgkinaeebnm\, I knew it was going to be there!

Answer (score 3):

As was mentioned, you can find it in appdata folder, e.g.:
C:\Users\mizer\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\

Hint: Sort folders by date and you can easily find the one you want :)

Answer (score 1):

For Chromium, this doesn't seem to work, as the manifest.json is located in:
/home/[[USER]]/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cdfdkmklcjlnnnlnplffpdiekfhkpbme/2.1_0

And modifying and saving this, doesn't reflect on a change in Chromium.
I presume Chromium (nearly the same as Chrome), loads up this config file in cache of some sorts...

Answer (score 1):

You can edit any chrome theme you want.

Just search for the extension-folder, it should be somewhere around here:

```
C:\Users\{USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\
```

(Obviously {USERNAME} needs to be replaced)

Afterwards open the manifest.json file (i.e. with your editor).
You can now make any changes you want. Simply edit the RGB-colors.
You can also copy complete new images to the extension-folder and reference to them in the manifest.

**Important:** After editing the manifest, you have to delete "Cached Theme" (its a PAK-file). Otherwise your changes will be ignored! You can find this file in the extension folder too.

Comment: About how to reload you can go to chrome://extensions, click Load unpacked extensions in the top right, then find the theme file and click select folder then it should work.